# How to load Codeigniter 4 lang file into an array variable

Tags: php, arrays, localization, lang, codeigniter-4

Is there a way to load a file from Codeignier 4 Language directory and assign the array content to a variable. Instead of returning the translated line, I want the whole array.

Like in CI3 we could do `$language = $this->lang->load('lang_file','english', TRUE);`.
But in CI4 I cant seem to find a workaround.

Comment: its a php file which return's an array, if all else fails you could simply do `$language = include('./Language/english.php')` etc

Answer (score 0):

If your lang array has a parent you can just do it like this:

```
return [
    'list' => [
        'Apples',
        'Bananas',
        'Grapes',
        'Lemons',
        'Oranges',
        'Strawberries'
    ]
];


$foo = lang('Fruit.list');
```

If that is not your case you can just do like @Lawrence Cherone said in the comments and just include the file.

```
$language = include('./Language/english.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

please use the below code to load the required language file as array

```
<?php
$locale = service('request')->getLocale();
$path = "Language/{$locale}/Validation.php";
$lang =  require APPPATH.$path; ;
var_dump($lang);
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).